# Find Similar words on levenshtein distance/ Fuzz Score

Tags: pandas, spell-checking, levenshtein-distance

I am trying to clean search term **scraped** from website. Since the search terms are from a ecommerce website they cannot be corrected using a PYspellchecker.
After research I came to know we can use levenshtein distance but i do not know how to implement it on a single column. I have 300K search terms and only way it is possible may be using a transpose of df. But it is not working as I am getting a memory out of bound error.

```
from pandas import DataFrame

Cars = {'Words': ['Walmart','Walnart','Audi','Aoudi','udi','Falmart','Audi A4'],
        'count': [22000,300,27000,300,50,300,3000]
        }

df = DataFrame(Cars,columns= ['Words', 'count'])
```

Words   count
Walmart 22000
Walnart 300
Audi    27000
Aoudi   300
udi 50
Falmart 300
Audi A4 3000

I want results like below

```
Words   Similar_word    Score
Walmart Walmart 100
Walnart Walmart 90
Audi    Audi    100
Aoudi   Audi    90
udi Audi    85
Falmart Walmart 85
Audi A4 Audi A4 100
```

where my logic does not compare Walmart with Audi. Secondly Audi A4 is 3 levenshtein distance apart hence it is treated at a seperate term.

Comment: I don't see the code here that actually produced the memory error, but the problem may be that you're comparing every word in the 300K with every other word.  But there's no way around that: if you're using Levenshtein to determine similarity in the first place, you don't know that "Walmart" and "Audi" are highly dissimilar until you've compared them and observed how different they are.  You can filter the result of the comparison afterwards, to keep only close matches, but there's no way to avoid comparing everything in the first place.